# Create a tcbcolorbox with multiple tags, and then put all relevants boxes in a list (depending) on their tag

Tags: tcolorbox, indexing, exercises

My problem is the following.
I want to create exercises (without using the package exercise) using tcolorbox.
The thing is I want to be able to index these exercises depending:
-their level of difficulty (let's say: basic, intermediate and difficult)
-the theme(s) treated in the exercise (for example: integral, complex numbers, sequences,.....)

Then I want to be able to create a list of all basic exercises, and one with all difficult exercises, ... and then one list with all the exercises that treat complex numbers, then another one with all exercises that are difficult and treat of integral, and so on and so forth.

So far the best MWE I have is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,list inside=infobox]{infobox}[2][]{
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  before=\vskip25pt,
  after=\vskip25pt,
  colback=white,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  toptitle=5pt,
  bottomtitle=5pt,
  left=10pt,
  right=10pt,
  enlarge left by=10pt,
  enlarge right by=10pt,
  width=\textwidth-20pt,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
%  title={\strut Box~\thetcbcounter\ #1\strut},
  title={\strut Exercise  \#~\thetcbcounter\ #1\strut},
  label={#2}
}

\newcommand\listboxname{List of Basic Exercises}




%%%%%%%%%%

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,list inside=infoboxmedium]{infoboxmedium}[2][]{
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  before=\vskip25pt,
  after=\vskip25pt,
  colback=white,
  colbacktitle=white,
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  toptitle=5pt,
  bottomtitle=5pt,
  left=10pt,
  right=10pt,
  enlarge left by=10pt,
  enlarge right by=10pt,
  width=\textwidth-20pt,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  %title={\strut Medium Level Exercise  \#~\thetcbcounter\ #1\strut},
  title={\strut Exercise  \#~\thetcbcounter\ #1\strut},
  label={#2}
}

\newcommand\listboxemediumname{List of Medium Level Exercises}

%%%%%%%%%%



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\tcblistof[\section*]{infobox}{\listboxname}

\tcblistof[\section*]{infoboxmedium}{\listboxemediumname}



\section{Heading}



\begin{infoboxmedium}[Title of the first test box]{orgspecialblock1infoboxmedium}
\lipsum[2]
\end{infoboxmedium}



\lipsum[4]
\begin{infobox}[Title of the first Exercise]{orgspecialblock1}
\lipsum[4]
\end{infobox}

\begin{infobox}[Title of the second Exercise]{orgspecialblock2}
\lipsum[4]
\end{infobox}






\section{Remainder}



\end{document}
```

It works fine but does only do the separation between basic, intermediate and difficult exercises. Besides, since it requires a different structure for each category, it will not be possible to extend that to all themes (integral, complex numbers, .....)

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think that `tcolorbox` only allows one `list inside` option but, maybe, with `tocloft` help you can add everybox into differents lists.

Comment: If you say so I believe you.
Any MWE which shows that?
Best,